# Join 2 DataSet<Row> in java spark to merge into single DataSet<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, join

I have 2 DataSet<Row>

[image]

[image]

I want the resultant to be a DataSet which is combined of both Resultant DataSet<Row>

[image]

using Java Spark

I have tried to do simple join

```
dataset1.join(dataset2).show();
```

but I am getting an error

> Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans

Other way I tied to do as full outer Join

```
dataset1.join(dataset2,dataset1.col("A").equalTo(dataset2.col("B")),"outer").show();
```

but it is coming with null entries

[image]

But I want resultant to be something like this one

[image]

Can someone suggest me other way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For join rows with the same positions, position can be added by Window `row_number` function to each dataset, and outer join performed by this column. On Scala, guess, can be converted to Java easily:

```
val first = Seq(
  ("as", 7),
  ("bs", 5),
  ("cs", 3),
  ("ds", 1)
).toDF("A", "B")

val second = Seq(
  ("rs", 1, 3, 5),
  ("rd", 3, 6, 8)
).toDF("C", "D", "E", "F")

val naturalOrderWindow = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
val result = first
  .withColumn("position", row_number().over(naturalOrderWindow))
  .join(second.withColumn("position", row_number().over(naturalOrderWindow)), Seq("position"), "outer")
  .drop("position")
```

Result is:

```
+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|A  |B  |C   |D   |E   |F   |
+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|as |7  |rs  |1   |3   |5   |
|bs |5  |rd  |3   |6   |8   |
|cs |3  |null|null|null|null|
|ds |1  |null|null|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Note: Window without partition is used, performance can be bad.

Comment: Can you please help me in getting rid of these null entries at the bottom.

Comment: Dataframe "na" functions can be used for replace nulls, example is here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-how-to-replace-null-values/